# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named : xml_parser & augments

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm

```
import augments
import xml_parser

pip3 install 'augments'
pip3 install 'xml_parser'


augments : image, corners = augments
paser :  xml = xml_parser.parse(xml_path)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'augments'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml_parser'

Comment: Did you install them? How did you do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that interpreter specified in settings has these packages: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that `pip3` and `python3` you run were using the same libraries. There may be multiple `python` on your system.

Comment: python --version == 3.7.4

Comment: @unyeol check library directory and compares with `pip3` install destination.